# Custom MKAnnotationView Showing Wrong Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

I have an `MKMapView` where I want to display annotations of contacts' faces.  I looked at Apple's sample app [MapCallouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html) and have so far written this:

**Annotation.h**

```
@interface Annotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

+ (MKAnnotationView *)createViewAnnotationForMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation;

@end
```

**Annotation.m**

```
#import "CustomAnnotationView.h"

@implementation Annotation

+ (MKAnnotationView *)createViewAnnotationForMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *returnedAnnotationView =
    (CustomAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"Annotation"];
    if (returnedAnnotationView == nil)
    {
        returnedAnnotationView =
        [[CustomAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                         reuseIdentifier:@"Annotation"];
    }

    return returnedAnnotationView;
}

@end
```

**CustomAnnotationView.h**

```
@interface CustomAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView
```

**CustomAnnotationView.m**

```
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{

    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Annotation"];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        Annotation *mapItem = (Annotation *)self.annotation;

        // Create imageView and labels, etc.
    }

    return self;
}
```

Then, to drop my annotation, I have this method which loops through an array of contacts, gets their address, finds the CLLOcationCoordinate2D, and creates an `Annotation`.

```
-(void)sortContacts{

    for (APContact *contact in self.peopleArray){

          [operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

            NSString *addressString = // get address from contact;

            contact.addressString = addressString;

                CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
                [geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressString
                             completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                                 if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0 && !error) {

                                     CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                                     CLLocation *location = topResult.location;
                                     CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;

                                         Annotation *annotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
                                         annotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Annotation"];

                                         if (contact.thumbnail.size.width > 0){
                                            annotation.image = contact.thumbnail;
                                         }
                                         else{
                                            annotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Annotation"];
                                         }

                                         annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
                                         [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
                                 }
                                 else if (error){
                                     NSLog(@"ERROR");
                                 }
                            }
                 ];
        }];
    }
}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    CustomAnnotationView *returnedAnnotationView = nil;

           if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]])
        {
            returnedAnnotationView = (CustomAnnotationView *)[Annotation createViewAnnotationForMapView:self.mapView annotation:annotation];
        }

    return returnedAnnotationView;
}
```

However, when I scroll across `self.mapView`, the incorrect contact images are showing for the wrong annotations. I'm not sure how to fix this.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: "Then, to drop my annotation, I have this method which loops through an array of contacts, gets their address, finds the CLLOcationCoordinate2D, and creates a..." And creates a what?

Comment: @LyndseyScott Whoops sorry, forgot to add 'Annotation'.  :)

Comment: Looks like an annotation view re-use issue.  In createViewAnnotationForMapView, if a view is dequeued, its annotation and image are not updated (and so image of previous annotation the view was used for is shown).

Comment: @Anna Aha, I don't know why I didn't think of that!  (Especially after using UITableView so much lately).  Your comment helped me think of the answer, which I answered below.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I added a property to my custom annotation view and simply changed the image everytime I dequeued or created a new annotation.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *annotationImage;
```